# 3 column css layout using only 2 divs

Tags: css

I'm trying to fix a page to have 3 columns. There are only 2 divs used for the contents I'm trying to work on. One that affects only the last part of the content, the other affects the entire content.

Basically here's how it sort of looks like right now:

> This is the first content-------------------This is the second content
>
> ```
>                              This is the third content
> ```

I've been trying to push the third content into the third column. I've tried using float right and it did move to the third column but below the other contents. I can't use a negative value for the margin-top either since this would overlap with the other contents if the window was resized. What I need to happen is something like this:

> ----This is the first content----This is the second content----This is the third content

I believe one big problem I'm having is that I'm not allowed to edit the html file for the page so all I'm working on is the css file.

Comment: Post your html/css code, or better, link a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What do you have access to? I would suggest making two divs, one with the left column and one with the right. Put the two divs that go into the right column in the div which floats right.

Comment: How does the html look like? I cant mod anything from this screen. Are there <p> or any other tags used besides divs?

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but apparently, I'm only allowed to make changes on the css file. Also, this is a project in joomla.

Comment: From what I saw on the source, there were only div tags on the page with textboxes and labels

Comment: @user1597438 Well can you post the html anyway. If we dont know exactly the build up from the page, we dont know what we can modify. Do you have a link to the page anyway to show us?

Answer (score 0):

code like this:

```
//Left:
float:left;

//MAIN:
margin-left: 20em; //these will define the width
margin-right: 20em;

//Right:
float:right;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use this add on in firefox called Firebug https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/ it will make your work easy since it shows you everything you change in CSS in real time on your browser in order that you can change it again when you have the correct view.

in your case i think you should try to check the size (width and height) of the div before trying to do the float right. because if the width cannot handle them both, the float right will not work.